# Transfer function of the below circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, transfer-function

How to find the transfer function of the below circuit?

Please specify the steps, as i would like to learn.

For anlysis, i consider V1 = 0 and all capacitor open. Thus,

Req = 14.7k // 14.7k = 7.35k, as R1 is short circuited

Thus, VR5 = (32x10k)/(10k+7.35k) = 18.44 V

but by simulaiton, the voltage across R5 = 28.9 V. What have i not considered?

[image]

Comment: You'd apply a full lecture worth of knowledge on linear network analysis. Sorry, your question is too broad as is and basically expects us to give you recap of a textbook. Please explain exactly how far you've gotten and ask a precise question *of your own*. Currently, you're just basically forwarding your assignment to us.

Comment: thanks for the edit! But this still makes no sense: your title asks for the transfer *function*, yet you simulate and calculate but a single voltage. That's not a transfer function.

Comment: Furthermore, if you set V1 = 0 and get anything but 0 V at the output, you must be doing something wrong, or have invented a machine that generates energy out of nothing, and thus have solved most problems on earth.

Comment: Furthermore, if your excitation is `SINE`, you can not assume all capacitors are open, that makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: So, I'm afraid, in total, this question still remains to broad: you seem to have skipped everything that concerned anything but constant current or constant voltage sources in resistor networks in what you've been learning from, and need to go back!

Answer (score 1):

I would have liked to comment that you have to be satisfied with just the calculations of various calculations, I apologize for the lack, but it would have required much more time and space, so you have to be satisfied with just the calculations, hoping that they are correct. Since these calculations made me quite tired, I didn't do a thorough check, but perhaps there's no need.  (Note: to avoid confusing Grad=Giga rad with the Grad gradient I added an s i.e.: krads, Mrads, Grads.)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the type of exercise where simplification is needed before running the analysis. First off, because the input is a voltage source, the first paralleled elements \$C_1R_1\$ have no impact on the response. Second, the circuit can gain in clarity if the remaining elements are rearranged in series. Finally, a few sketches with the fast analytical circuits techniques (FACTs) as I described them in my last [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1960405195) on the subject and the transfer function comes out easily with the low-\$Q\$ approximation:

[image]